Mount doesn't appear in fstab
When I run df -h on my server (redhat 9.4) I can see:
/dev/mapper/rhel-home 21G 391M 21G 2% /home
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv0 400G 2.9G 397G 1% /home/myuser/data_file
But when I look at /etc/fstab I can only see the:
/dev/mapper/rhel-home 21G 391M 21G 2% /home
The data_file is not there.
I can see it if I run: "cat /proc/self/mounts" But This file is read only.
How can I remove the data_file mount and put it in the /etc/fstab? I don't want it to be mount from any other place other then /etc/fstab.
Thanks.

One thing I can think of is handwritten systemd mount unit. (Or, one generated by/from something other than the fstab; but that's unlikely since it's obviously a "user mount" instead of something like snap or whatsoever). (Besides, do you mean like it would still be mounted after a reboot?)

Or maybe your DE or some udisks frontend running in your system automount everything (else) with udisks...
